# How does the VP9 implementation differ from the libvpx-vp9 implementation?

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg

I am having trouble understanding the differences between the multiple implementations of decoders in FFmpeg.

I am guessing that FFmpeg uses the following functions to register the codecs right? libavcodec/vp9.c -> ff_vp9_decoder:

```
const FFCodec ff_vp9_decoder = {
    .p.name                = "vp9",
    CODEC_LONG_NAME("Google VP9"),
    .p.type                = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
    .p.id                  = AV_CODEC_ID_VP9,
    .priv_data_size        = sizeof(VP9Context),
    .init                  = vp9_decode_init,
    .close                 = vp9_decode_free,
    FF_CODEC_DECODE_CB(vp9_decode_frame),
    .p.capabilities        = AV_CODEC_CAP_DR1 | AV_CODEC_CAP_FRAME_THREADS | AV_CODEC_CAP_SLICE_THREADS,
    .caps_internal         = FF_CODEC_CAP_INIT_CLEANUP |
                             FF_CODEC_CAP_SLICE_THREAD_HAS_MF |
                             FF_CODEC_CAP_ALLOCATE_PROGRESS,
    .flush                 = vp9_decode_flush,
    UPDATE_THREAD_CONTEXT(vp9_decode_update_thread_context),
    .p.profiles            = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL(ff_vp9_profiles),
    .bsfs                  = "vp9_superframe_split",
    .hw_configs            = (const AVCodecHWConfigInternal *const []) {
#if CONFIG_VP9_DXVA2_HWACCEL
                               HWACCEL_DXVA2(vp9),
#endif
#if CONFIG_VP9_D3D11VA_HWACCEL
                               HWACCEL_D3D11VA(vp9),
#endif
#if CONFIG_VP9_D3D11VA2_HWACCEL
                               HWACCEL_D3D11VA2(vp9),
#endif
#if CONFIG_VP9_NVDEC_HWACCEL
                               HWACCEL_NVDEC(vp9),
#endif
#if CONFIG_VP9_VAAPI_HWACCEL
                               HWACCEL_VAAPI(vp9),
#endif
#if CONFIG_VP9_VDPAU_HWACCEL
                               HWACCEL_VDPAU(vp9),
#endif
#if CONFIG_VP9_VIDEOTOOLBOX_HWACCEL
                               HWACCEL_VIDEOTOOLBOX(vp9),
#endif
                               NULL
                           },
};
```

And for libvpx in libavcodec/libvpxdec.c -> ff_libvpx_vp9_decoder:

```
FFCodec ff_libvpx_vp9_decoder = {
    .p.name         = "libvpx-vp9",
    CODEC_LONG_NAME("libvpx VP9"),
    .p.type         = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
    .p.id           = AV_CODEC_ID_VP9,
    .p.capabilities = AV_CODEC_CAP_OTHER_THREADS,
    .p.profiles     = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL(ff_vp9_profiles),
    .p.wrapper_name = "libvpx",
    .priv_data_size = sizeof(VPxContext),
    .init           = vp9_init,
    .close          = vpx_free,
    FF_CODEC_DECODE_CB(vpx_decode),
    .caps_internal  = FF_CODEC_CAP_NOT_INIT_THREADSAFE |
                      FF_CODEC_CAP_AUTO_THREADS,
    .init_static_data = ff_vp9_init_static,
};
```

My question is how do these implementations differ and why are there even multiple implementations?

I have seen that libvpx supports alpha and the 'vp9' implementation supports hardware acceleration. Are there any other differences?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please don't tag multiple different languages, only the one you're actually programming in.

Comment: How they differ? But you answered it yourself. Why several? Because nothing can support all needs of all competitors in video streaming business equally well and be the best for each of them at same time. Plus no player in that business is interested in paying for developing such thing even if it was possible.